# How to position Layouts in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to make the following GUI.. each python class was made and working well with the name suggested below.

[image]

For example, elements_structure related class is looking like

```
class Elements_Structure():
    def __init__(self, root):
        super(Elements_Structure, self).__init__(root)
        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):
        label = Label(self, text="Elements Structure", font=("Arial",12)).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        cols = ('L#', 'Layer Name', 'Material', 'Refractive Index', 'Thickness', 'Unit')
        listBox = Treeview(self, columns=cols, show='headings')
```

and the main entry code is looking like,

```
from tkinter import *
from components.elements_structure import *
from components.emission_layer import *
from components.emission_zone_setting import *
from components.file_tab import *
from components.logo_image import *


def main(root):
    top_frame = Frame(root, width=1980, height=780).grid(rowspan=4, columnspan=4)
    bottom_frame = Frame(root, width=1980, height=230).grid(columnspan=4)

    elements_structure_graph = Frame(top_frame, width=480, height=780).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4)
    elements_structure = Frame(top_frame, width=960, height=690).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, columnspan=2)

    logo_image = Frame(top_frame, width=480, height=230).grid(row=0, column=2)
    logo_properties = Frame(top_frame, width=480, height=230).grid(row=1, column=2)
    logo_execute = Frame(top_frame, width=480, height=230).grid(row=2, column=2)

    emission_layer = Frame(top_frame, width=1440, height=100).grid(row=2, column=2, colspan=3)
    emission_layer_graph = Frame(bottom_frame, width=480, height=290).grid(row=0, column=0)

    emission_zone_setting = Frame(bottom_frame, width=480, height=290).grid(row=0, column=2)
    emission_zone_setting_graph = Frame(bottom_frame, width=480, height=290).grid(row=0, column=1)

    logo_project_info = Frame(bottom_frame, width=480, height=290).grid(row=0, column=3)

    root.title("JooAm Simulator")
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1920, 1080))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    File_Tab(root)
    main(root)
```

But I seemed to miss the link between the class and the tkinter window object.

How can I make the above structure with the library tkinter?

Thank you in advance~!!

Comment: What is the output that you have, as of now. Also you have a typo in `emission_layer`, it should be `columnspan`. Also keep a note that all your widgets are `None` which means, they are non reusable later on.

Answer (score 0):

Lot to deal with here. Can't work on the code without the components file.
Most on what is in main should be in create_GUI.
I like to start with something like:
class OLED_Display:
def **init**(self, master):
self.master = master
self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
bg_color='light green'
self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Constants',
width = 35, command = 'ANY USER FUNCTION', bg=bg_color)
You can try from there or provide more info.